# "Missing values" when creating a Bar Chart with ggplot2

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a very simple table with three rows (categories) and three numeric values. My goal is to create a bar chart with ggplot2.

Please, can anyone tell me a solution to my problem? I have no idea what's wrong here.

[R code that I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re5Y3.png)

I checked the values of the table, but they are fine.

The problem seems to be in the line «scale_y_continuous (limits = c(1, 5))», as the problem does not occur when I remove this line. At the same time, I want the y-axis to start at 1 and end at 5.

Comment: Have you tried `, na.rm = TRUE` option in `geom_bar` function?

Comment: Please don't share code as images, share as formatted plain textt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the solution is not to set these limits via the scale_y_* but rather by coord_carterisian. i.e.

```
`your code` + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,5))
```

minor points

1. prefer geom_col() to geom_bar(stat="identity")
2. when you want to share code, which is text, better to put it on stack overflow as formatted text, than to screenshot and share a link.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, Nir! Thank you so much.